# can uiimageview image be set through the xcode designer?

Tags: xcode

I'm working on a LaunchScreen.storyboard for a project.  I've added a UIImageView to the storyboard.  I would expect there to be a way to associate an image through the xcode designer but I don't see a way to do this.

I googled this topic and only found references to doing this programmatically instead of through the xcode designer.  So is there a way to do this through the designer or can this only be done programmatically? If this can only be done programmatically then what's the rationale behind this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

When you select your UIImageView in your Launchscreen.storyboard, select the attributes inspector:

[image]

You should be seeing something similar to this:

[image]

In this dropwdown you can choose an image from your image assets.

Hope this helps!